# jTable Modal Style

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jtable

I am using jTable Metro blue theme but the default jQuery UI theme is shown for add/edit modal but it should be matched to the jTable's theme. I include the following files:

```
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Scripts/jtable/themes/metro/blue/jtable.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jtable/jquery.jtable.min.js"></script>
```

This is how it looks:
[image: Add/Edit Modal]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, I had to grab jquery-UI css from another source. The answer is posted [here](https://github.com/hikalkan/jtable/issues/1121)

Answer (score 0):

Try going to jtable.org/Themes and view the theme you want.

On my case I chose [metro blue theme](http://jtable.org/Demo/Theme?jTableStyle=metro/blue/jtable.css)

[image: jtable.org screen shot]

Go to developer tools>Sources>themes/YOURTHEME
then copy the content of jquery-ui.css and paste it on your own jquery-ui.css

also include jquery-ui.structure.css

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(). 'jtable/themes/metro/blue/jtable.css' ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="<?php echo base_url(). 'css/jquery-ui.css' ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="<?php echo base_url(). 'css/jquery-ui.structure.css' ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Hope that helps! ;)